# How to get dependencies from external projects in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I use ExternalProject_Add for libgit2 which compiles this library as static library. Linking to this library works fine but there are some dependencies missing when linking. Is there any way to get these dependencies when using exteranl projects?

Comment: Very late comment, but it probably would have helped if you provided more details: which dependencies? have you taken a look at the github issues to see if anyone has had a similar issue?